# urllib.request.urlopen not stop

Tags: python, urllib

I am trying to get html source by using urllib.request.open.

I don't know why my code did not stop.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = "https://google.com"
try:
    page = urlopen(url)
    f = open("google.html","wb")
    f.write(page.read())
except:
    print("Error")
```

But with timeout, it received the source.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = "https://google.com"
try:
    page = urlopen(url, timeout=0.1)
    f = open("google.html","wb")
    f.write(page.read())
except:
    print("Error")
```

Comment: Why do you mean with "my code did not stop"? I ran your code with python3 and it executes correctly.

Comment: I ran the first code with python3.7 on linux and it ran forever.

Comment: How do you run your program? I've executed over the Docker image of python (GNU/Linux) and on mac and it runs fine.

Comment: i ran them in terminal and pycharm